# How to hide the border around the panel created by jscrollbar?

Tags: java, swing

After I added JScrollbar to my Jpanel I noticed that it created a border around my jpanel which looks very weird. From the attached figure you can see that the JPanel "Plot fault domain" in GUI contains a second border. How can I keep the scrollbar but hide the border? thanks.
[image: My GUI front end]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to set an empty border to the JScrollBar.

```
JScrollBar jsb = ...;
jsb.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```